# How does this Objective-C code work?

Tags: objective-c, methods, runtime

Code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    id idObject = @"12345";
    NSNumber *n = idObject;

    NSLog(@"%@\n", [n description]);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints "12345". How? I guess it's because Objective-C uses dynamic binding. Thus, decision which method to choose is made at run-time and this decision is based on the name of the method (selector) and the receiver object. Maybe the receiver object gets known due to "isa" pointer... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works because:

1. All objects that inherit from `NSObject` have a `description` method.
2. Objective-C doesn't enforce types, so `n` is actually an `NSString` and not an `NSNumber` as you might suppose.

Comment: Yes. Plus, actually, this get converted into objc_MsgSend(id receiver,...), where the receiver is of type - "id". Then, to find the correct implementation run-time uses "isa" to get the corresponding class the "receiver" belongs to and then the methods list of that class is looked up. Thanks to this article: http://danie.lt/ios/development/objective-c/2013/08/03/how-objective-c-messaging-works.html

Answer (score 3):

You are right.

The code works, because `n` refers to an object that understands the message `description`. (The object is a instance object of class `NSString` and these objects understand that message.)

The type of the object reference `n` (`id`, `NSString*`, `NSNumber*`, `whatever`) is without any meaning for the dispatching process.

At runtime you can collect many information about objects and its types. You cannot collect information about object references. (There is a single case, but this is not important.)

Answer (score 2):

To add:

You're not actually typecasting by setting `idObject` to be referenced by `NSNumber * n`. The compiler doesn't know what type `id` should be, so it allows you to assign it to anything.

With your code snippet running you can see a bit more on how this is played out:

[image]

And then for comparison (creating an NSNumber from the string literal):

[image]